# TortoiseHg complains that it can't find Python

Tags: python, mercurial, tortoisehg

I am trying to use TortoiseHg on my Mac OS X 10.6. I downloaded the most recent TortoiseHg. The mac came with Python 2.6, but I installed 2.7:

```
ftwomfg-63-12:~ muffins$ python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

When I try to launch TortoiseHg, I get the following error:

> thg[18006]    A Python runtime not could be located.  You may need to
>   install a framework build of Python, or edit the PyRuntimeLocations
>   array in this application's Info.plist file.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try to add the Python interpreter to your path (edit `PATH` on `.bash_profile`)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path to Python by typing in:

```
which python
```

which might return something like:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/Python

Next, you'll want to edit the file Info.plist, inside the directory TortoiseHg.app/Contents.  Inside the file, you'll see something like:

```
<key>PyRuntimeLocations</key>
<array>
    <string>@executable_path/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python</string>
    <string>/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python</string>
</array>
```

You'll want to change the contents of the second string to the path from the which command above.